# How do you select a specific row from a group in a group_by statement in python SQLAlchemy (sqlite)?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble with what seems like it should be a very simple query. For each unique name, I want to return only the name of the user with the lowest age

Here is a **Basic example**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce2f7e4/16

Sample database:

```
 +-----+-------+-----+
| id  | name  | age |
+-----+-------+-----+
|  1  | joe   |  50 |
|  2  | joe   |  25 |
|  3  | fred  |  25 |
|  4  | fred  |  50 |
|  5  | bob   |  30 |
+-----+-------+-----+
```

This is the **Current attempt** I'm trying:

```
session.query(User).group_by(User.name).order_by(User.name,User.age).all()
```

In raw SQL:

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.age from user t
GROUP BY t.name
ORDER BY t.name, t.age;
```

However this returns the wrong result as you can see in the example. I get one row for each name as needed, but the user selected is not the one with the lowest age for each unique name.

**Desired result:**

```
+-----+-------+-----+
| id  | name  | age |
+-----+-------+-----+
|  2  | joe   |  25 |
|  3  | fred  |  25 |
|  5  | bob   |  30 |
+-----+-------+-----+
```

As you can see, for each unique name the row returned should be the user with that name who has the lowest age. How can I write an sqlalchemy query to get this result? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to translate it to sqlachemy, but in straight up SQL, you'd use a ranking window function like `row_number()`:

```
WITH ranked(id, name, age, rn) AS
  (SELECT id, name, age, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY age) AS rn
   FROM test)
SELECT id, name, age
FROM ranked
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY name, age;
```

[DB<>Fiddle demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d1170408b23189990a2f3d9a0c6cd522)

Or the Sqlite-specific:

```
SELECT id, name, min(age) AS age
FROM test
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name, age;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the youngest row, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.age = (select min(t2.age) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```